# Attached monitor is off, but window is still there, and I can't move the application back to active monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-mate

I sometimes use an external monitor on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  However, the monitor is off now.

The problem is that sometimes application windows will get sent to the deactivated monitor, upon which they cannot be accessed at all.

If I right-click the application button on the taskbar, no option shows that I can move the application to the active monitor.

How can I access the applications that are on the inactive monitor and/or move the windows to the active monitor?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have an external monitor which I share between my laptop/desktop. When I change the "source" to the desktop computer, Ubuntu still keeps my "active" window on that screen, until I disconnect the HDMI